# Grails GORM mapping tries to access field "class" which exists nowhere

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

This is pretty strange.

```
class Service implements Serializable{

Integer id
String serviceName
String description
SortedSet serviceRequirements

static hasMany = [ serviceRequirements : ServiceRequirement]

static mapping = 
{
    table 'service'

    columns {
        id column:'serviceId'

    }
}}
```

The resulting hibernate sql when accessing serviceInstance.serviceRequirements is:

```
  servicereq0_.serviceId as serviceId1_,
    servicereq0_.serviceRequirementId as serviceR1_1_,
    servicereq0_.serviceRequirementId as serviceR1_9_0_,
    servicereq0_.version as version9_0_,
    servicereq0_.description as descript3_9_0_,
    servicereq0_.header as header9_0_,
    servicereq0_.isPersonal as isPersonal9_0_,
    servicereq0_.requirementKey as requirem6_9_0_,
    servicereq0_.required as required9_0_,
    servicereq0_.serviceId as serviceId9_0_,
    servicereq0_.type as type9_0_,
    servicereq0_.weight as weight9_0_,
    servicereq0_.oauthAccessTokenUrl as oauthAc12_9_0_,
    servicereq0_.oauthAuthorizeAdditionalParameters as oauthAu13_9_0_,
    servicereq0_.oauthAuthorizeState as oauthAu14_9_0_,
    servicereq0_.oauthAuthorizeUrl as oauthAu15_9_0_,
    servicereq0_.oauthClientId as oauthCl16_9_0_,
    servicereq0_.oauthClientSecret as oauthCl17_9_0_,
    servicereq0_.oauthRequestTokenUrl as oauthRe18_9_0_,
    servicereq0_.oauthType as oauthType9_0_,
    servicereq0_.class as class9_0_
```

All fields are ok except the last "class". It doesn't exist at all in the database or the domain class called ServiceRequirement.

Comment: Could you also show the ServiceRequirement class code?

Comment: Unrelated - you don't need to specify the `id` field (even when you want to customize it in the `mapping` block) since Grails autogenerates it for you. Also you can omit the table name mapping since that's what the name would be anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column named `class` is automatically added to a table when it stores multiple classes.  If the `ServiceRequirement` class has a subclass that is also a domain class, then the table will need a `class` column to know what kind of `ServiceRequirement` it is.  Grails is generally smart enough to automatically add the column if `dbCreate` is set, but you'll need to add it yourself if you're managing your schema manually.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. And yes, I wasn't letting grails generate tables so that could be it. Seems like a weird way to map stuff with class names...